# getting Null or empty records in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a database with form, the form has 3 combo boxes to filter the table using query,
the query has multiple criteras and I am trying to add one critera based on combo box to show empty records if the value of the combobox is No

I tried this in the critera with no luck

```
If([Forms]![Statusfrm]![Combo95] = "Yes", Like"".Nz(" IMNotifications].[Order]))
```

appreceate your help

Comment: I tired also Is Null but it is not returning null fields!

Answer (score 1):

Correct function is IIf() not If().

Consider:
`WHERE IIf([Forms]![Statusfrm]![Combo95] = "Yes", Not [Order] Is Null, [Order] Is Null)`

Make sure the 'empty' fields are actually Null and not empty string. I always set text fields in table design to not allow empty string. Or consider code that handles both:

`WHERE IIf([Forms]![Statusfrm]![Combo95] = "Yes", [Order] & "" <> "", [Order] & "" = "")`

or if you want all records when combobox is "Yes":

`WHERE [Order] & "" LIKE IIf([Forms]![Statusfrm]![Combo95] = "Yes", "*", "")`

I don't use dynamic parameterized queries. I prefer to build criteria with VBA and apply to form or report when opening.